# React Without JSX Rendered more hook than previous render when children has useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a list with React that each element of the list would need to change over time, and the list itself would grow over time.

During the initialization step everything was drawn correctly, the child's update is also working without issue. However, when I add another child to the list, the whole list collapsed with the error information of Rendered more hook than previous render.

I am following the Rule of Hooks of putting `React.useEffect` as well as `React.useState` at the beginning of all functions, and there is also no conditional statement in the program. Can anyone point to what I did wrong that caused such issue?

JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/xtkz1fqn/1/

Code of a demo component:

```js
function MyList(listItem){
        const [lastUpdate, setLastUpdate] = React.useState(Date.now());
        let suffix = "";
        React.useEffect(()=>{
                let timer = setTimeout(()=>{ setLastUpdate(Date.now()); }, 1000);
                return ()=>{ clearTimeout(timer); }
        },[]);
        return React.createElement("li", {"key": listItem}, listItem + " - " + lastUpdate);
}

function DemoList(){
        const [dataSet, setDataSet] = React.useState(["initialItem - "+Date.now()]);
        React.useEffect(()=>{
                let timer = setTimeout(()=>{
                        setDataSet(dataSet.concat(["newItem - "+Date.now()]));
                },10000);
                return ()=>{ clearTimeout(timer); }
        },[dataSet]);
        return React.createElement("ul", null, dataSet.map((item)=>MyList(item)));
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("react-root"));
reactRoot.render(React.createElement(React.StrictMode, null, React.createElement(DemoList)));
```

Expected behavior:

1. For every 10 seconds, a new list item would be added to the list.
2. When a new item is added to the list, its text would be updated once in 1 second.

However, the addition of the second item into the list breaks everything.

### Solution

Thanks for pointing out that the function component is not used by calling it, but calling one more React.createElement on it. There is also another mistake on my component parameter definition so I also need a fix there.

The 2 modifications to fix the code are shown below.

```
1c1
< function MyList(listItem){
---
> function MyList({listItem}){
19c19
<         return React.createElement("ul", null, dataSet.map((item)=>MyList(item)));
---
>         return React.createElement("ul", null, dataSet.map((item)=>React.createElement(MyList, {"key": item, "listItem": item})));
```

### Final words

The React documentation on React without JSX does not have contain an example with children. After trying both `dataSet.map((item)=>React.createElement(MyList(item)))` and `dataSet.map((item)=>React.createElement(MyList, item))` with no avail, I took the only seemingly working way of `dataSet.map((item)=>MyList(item))`. It is only after I starting adding those Effects that it turned out I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*putting React.useEffect as well as React.useState at the beginning of all functions* is not a part of the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Yes they should not be called conditionally and should always be called the same number of times. The order also should not change.

From the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html):

> Fundamentally, JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the React.createElement(component, props, ...children) function.

So the below two items are not equivalent :

```
<MyList listItem={item}></MyList>
```

and

```
Mylist(item)
```

When the second one is run, react has no way to tell that the code inside Mylist method is running in the context of a different react component. For it the statement `const [lastUpdate, setLastUpdate] = React.useState(Date.now());` might as well be running inside `DemoList`. And if that happens then the hook `useState` is running inside `DemoList`. And for every new item you add you will be adding more and more hook calls inside `DemoList`. And then the number of hooks inside `DemoList` have essentially changed breaking the rule of hooks.

The reason the first time it allows you to run is because the first time it consider all 4 of your hooks to be a part of `DemoList`. But from next render onwards a new hook `useState` is added which was initially not part of the hook sequence.

```
, "DemoList", "1. useState                   useState
2. useEffect                  useEffect
3. useState                   useState
4. useEffect                  useEffect
5. undefined                  useState
", "
```

Just convert to [JSX to solve this](https://jsfiddle.net/e43v1agh/15/)
Here is the code:

```
"use strict"

function MyList({listItem}){
        const [lastUpdate, setLastUpdate] = React.useState(Date.now());
        let suffix = "";
        React.useEffect(()=>{
                let timer = setTimeout(()=>{ setLastUpdate(Date.now()); }, 1000);
                return ()=>{ clearTimeout(timer); }
        },[]);
        return React.createElement("li", {"key": listItem}, listItem + " - " + lastUpdate);
}

function DemoList(){
        const [dataSet, setDataSet] = React.useState(["initialItem - "+Date.now()]);
        React.useEffect(()=>{
                let timer = setTimeout(()=>{
                        setDataSet(dataSet.concat(["newItem - "+Date.now()]));
                },10000);
                return ()=>{ clearTimeout(timer); }
        },[dataSet]);
        return React.createElement("ul", null, dataSet.map((item)=><MyList listItem={item}></MyList>));
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("react-root"));
reactRoot.render(React.createElement(React.StrictMode, null, React.createElement(DemoList)));
```

[Read](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component)

Comment: Thanks for your info. I did attempt to call React.createElement for a few times but failed to spot the correct way of specifying the parameters when creating the component. The official documentation of React without JSX also made no mention on children part of the React.createElement. I fixed my code with the following modifications: 1. Add curly brackets to the parameter of MyList so it looks like {listItem} now. 2. Instead of calling my MyList(listItem) in the map function, use React.createElement(MyList, {"listItem": item}).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have written in my codefiddle also. Sorry if it was not obvious. But in 2, I used JSX itself yes.